# Does the time command include the memory claimed by forked processes?

Tags: linux, memory, time, benchmark

I want to benchmark some scripts with the `time` command. I am wondering if this command catches child processes' memory usage.

```
command time -f '%M' python my_script.py
```

If not, what are my options? Is `valgrind` suitable for this purpose?

I also don't want to double count copy-on-write memory that is not actually filling up space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does. Just compare `command time -v ksh -c exit` with `command time -v ksh -c java`. And be impressed.

Comment: How does it not double counts the copy-on-write memory consumption of forked processes?

Comment: @HappyFace this being a Linux question, the source code for time is freely available.

Comment: @HappyFace `time` doesn’t double-count it because the kernel doesn’t double-count it — it isn’t consumed, so it isn’t counted. `time` measures actual memory use, not memory allocations (otherwise the Java example would show the minimum heap allocation, which is much larger than the memory really used).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, `time` probably does little more than show some values returned by some system call, so it's really more like the Linux source code you'd need to check. The man page for the GNU version of `time` says "Most information shown by time is derived from the `wait3(2)` system call.  The numbers are only as good as those returned by `wait3(2)`.  On systems that do not have a `wait3(2)` call that returns status information, the `times(2)` system call is used instead."

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't be too tough to even create a test process that allocates loads of memory but touches little.

Comment: @ilkkachu in the context of the question, it’s the non-builtin version of `time` (since the Bash builtin doesn’t show memory usage). But yes, in any case it’s the kernel source code that’s relevant here ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt, good point, thanks. The question even had `command time` there, but I still can't read, so...

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is to use the `/proc/` file system. See [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details.

Your Python script might *directly* parse `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/self/statm` *without* forking any process.

Feel free to contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` (near Paris in France)